# Kong set Service timeouts via Helm Charts

Tags: kubernetes, service, kubernetes-helm, kong

I am trying to set the Timeouts for my Kong Service, which is deployed with Helm Charts.
In my Service.yaml file I added these annotations, as referenced in the Kong [Docs](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/references/annotations/).

```
annotations:
  konghq.com/connect-timeout: 120000
  konghq.com/write-timeout: 120000
  konghq.com/read-timeout: 120000
```

However in the deployment Process I get the following error:

```
>  Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.annotations of type string
```

Comment: pass it as the string what command are you running and facing the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the answer is simply pass the values as strings.

```
annotations:
  konghq.com/connect-timeout: "120000"
  konghq.com/write-timeout: "120000"
  konghq.com/read-timeout: "120000"
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same without any success. The configuration is applied on the service but it doesn't seems to be used. Do you have to do something else for getting this to work ?

metadata:
  annotations:
    konghq.com/connect-timeout: "180000"
    konghq.com/read-timeout: "180000"
    konghq.com/write-timeout: "180000"

Thanks

Comment: I did get errors when the form was not correct, but after that everything worked fine and it applied the settings. Is everything else deployed correctly?

Comment: It seems to be deployed correctly, my service is running since more than a year without any problems and the Kong Ingress controller was upgraded to the latest version (2.8). I miss something but it's hard to find since theres no feedback. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem? It seems that I now have the same problem, everything still works but my timeouts are not updated anymore

Comment: Nop i haven't found a solution for this, after several failed attempt... I'm really disappointed with kong.

Comment: Did you set the annotations to the Service object (not the Ingress)?
https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/reference/annotations/#service-resource